# Is it conventional to use verbs to describe relationships between classes in UML?

Tags: oop, uml, associations, class-diagram

I've come across resources that depict UML diagrams with verbs like 'wrote' to describe how one class uses another. Does this convention exist in UML; is it overkill to add this convention to my designs?

ex:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a common convention: the name over the association (`Wrote`) is the name of the association.  You may add the solid triangle to show the order of reading.

But often the associations are shown without name, or without the triangle,  if this information is not important for the understanding of the diagram.  Adding this systematically in the diagram might make it more difficult to read and give a feeling of information overload.  So, up to you to find the right balance in your specific case.

Comment: Actually _over_ is not quite correct. It's "somewhere near the center of the relation". The graphical positions are nor mathematically defined but somewhat blurry. The UML spec gives only example renderings and what can be said is the above. And probably it should be placed in a way to get not mixed up with role names.

Comment: I agree with everything but “information overload”. Just take the time to add space and avoid mess.

Comment: @JimL. thank you for your feedback. Indeed, I myself hesitated if it was not exagerated. Note that it was anyway meant to be hypothetical ("*might (…) give the feeling …*"). My point was more about those diagrams with dozen of associations, each with multiplicities, role and name+direction: wouldn’t this be difficult to read, due to the wealth of information?  Not to speak about the uncertainty it creates about where to start reading, to follow the triangles. (I speak for the occasional reader’s, not for the experts like you). But I can remove it, if you think it’s inappropriate.

Comment: @qwerty_so I used the descriotion of the diagram to explain that it was a name. This is why I mentionned “above” and “wrote”. My intent was not to substitute this answer to the specs, nor to make an abusive generalization ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. The trick is to create focused, interlinked diagrams, not a massive horse blanket. I’d rather motivate the former, which, unfortunately, seems to be somewhat of a rare art.

Comment: Another thing I find useful for information models is to never use association names, only association end names, in the form “writingProfessor” and “writtenTextbook”. This way, “wrote” is baked into the property names.

Comment: @JimL. this is indeed a very good advice. Personally, I also tend to use clear role names,  as I find it always more difficult to find unambiguous, compact and expressive association names (here it is obvious that author “wrote the book” and not “to the book”, but the difference is not always that obvious in more abstract models). I think later this week, I’ll edit the answer to make the substance of  our discussion more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to summarize a few experiences:

- Using the name/triangle notation is often advantageous when working with business stakeholders. In that case the triangle is mandatory because without it can lead to confusion. Not so in the above example but it should be a modeling rule set in the domain.
- Applying roles/multiplicities is practical when moving over to technical aspects. In that stage the label is not important any more as it can be guessed from the role names. So the best is to have diagrams for business people having just the labels/triangles and ones for techies containing roles/multiplicities.
- If for any case you want both notations make sure that you have enough space to distinguish between labels and role names. That makes dense diagrams impossible.

Like in a Chinese Restaurant: if there's all you can eat please listen to your stomach.